# Cannot plot rglscene object by means of plot3d() function of rgl R package

Tags: r, rgl

I am having trouble with the R package,`rgl` (version 0.95.1441),  in particular, I cannot reproduce the code from the Examples section of the documentation of the `scene3d rgl` function:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgl/docs/plot3d.rglscene

I am using R of version 3.2.4 and R studio 0.99.892 under Windows 8.

```
open3d()
z <- 2 * volcano        # Exaggerate the relief
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))   # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))   # 10 meter spacing (E to W)
persp3d(x, y, z, col = "green3", aspect = "iso")

s <- scene3d()
# Make it bigger
s$par3d$windowRect <- 1.5*s$par3d$windowRect
# and draw it again
plot3d(s)
```

I am able to produce a 3D image after calling the `persp3d` function and I was able to save the `rglscene` object into variable `s`. However, after executing the last string of the present listing, an extremely narrow window has appeared and it's not possible to see whether it contains anything or not. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no par3d component in s.  It is part of s$rootSubscene.  (That's not how it is documented, but that's how it is.)

If you want to double the size of your scene, you need to change two things:  the windowRect and the viewport.  So this works for me:

```
open3d()
z <- 2 * volcano        # Exaggerate the relief
x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z))   # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z))   # 10 meter spacing (E to W)
persp3d(x, y, z, col = "green3", aspect = "iso")

s <- scene3d()
# Make it bigger
par3d <- s$rootSubscene$par3d
par3d$windowRect <- 1.5*par3d$windowRect
par3d$viewport <- 1.5*par3d$viewport
s$rootSubscene$par3d <- par3d

# and draw it again
plot3d(s)
```

Comment: @user2554330Thank you so much!

Comment: Besides, one from the reasons of my troubles was multiple editing `s` variable. The code works for me correctly only when i explicitly deleted the variable before it creating (i many times played with code, so i created the mentioned variable many times as well). For example: `... rm(s) s <- scene3d() ...`  instead of simple overwriting by `... s <- scene3d()  ...` I don't understand why, but for me it was an important aspect.